# Node js ubuntu bin folder missing

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, bin

I am trying to setup Node Js in Ubuntu following the tutorial
 
[Install Ubuntu Node Js Via Zip](https://medium.com/@rabbi.cse.sust.bd/install-nodejs-via-binary-archive-on-ubuntu-18-04-63118473d9e9) and
 
[Install nodejs without package manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892265/install-nodejs-without-package-manager)

Downloading the Node JS Zip File from
 
[Nodejs.org/download/release/v10.12.0](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v10.12.0/)

They show us to add env path

```
# NodeJS
export NODEJS_HOME=/opt/node-v10.1.0-linux-x64/bin
export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME:$PATH
```

But the folder bin is missing from the latest release
Where can we find node and npm files in new versions ?

Comment: Maybe out of scope but you might want to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install/handle your node versions. It will allow you to have several versions of node installed and switch between them.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/) is best place to ask this, or check old posts [here](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: What do you mean by "the folder bin is missing" ? I can see it. Did you take the right .tar.gz file : `node-v10.12.0-linux-x64.tar.gz  ` ?

Comment: Thanks I had downloaded the wrong file "node-v10.12.0.tar.gz". Dont know why they have kept two files to confuse

Comment: Can you see a `src` folder in the zip you downloaded before ? In this case, it means that you had downloaded the source code.